Temporary waterproofing hole in the roof
I have this old retired roofbox I would like to remove (has mod bit material applied over cracked glass to waterproof) and install a new skylight on a 10 degree mod bit roof.

Once I demolish, I anticipate a few days before I can finalize the framing for the new and then again maybe a few days before I can get my roofing guy to apply the torchdown material around it for final protection. I have to outsource this because I am not good with the torch (I tried).
That brings the problem of how to protect this hole, that would be something like 24x36" (the base of this box) in the likely case of precipitation during the interim. Can I just use some torchdown material that comes in 3' wide rolls, which I do have and tape it with roofing tape (like you can see around the ports for HVAC lineset right above it, which has worked really well 10 years) after I put some plywood over? Of course I can't just use tarp because water would go right under it and into the opening.

It's tough to tell from your photo the direction, but where are you going to mount and demolish?
If it will be from the curb, no big deal - you can cover and seal and strap something around the curb that sticks up.
If it's deck mounted, you will need to either plan for some good days of weather, or protect it by covering with tarps repeatedly all the way up to the peak or edges, such that no areas that could feed moisture towards it are exposed - Google "How to tarp a roof" for several examples of this.
Your other option is to purposely flush it out and open, and put a bucket or something similar inside for it to drain into, should a storm happen. This is quite common when working on flat roofs.

I will remove everything that raises above the roof around it

I  can't tarp it because I can't tuck tarp under the roofing material because it is mod bit, not shingle

You wouldn't tuck it under, you tarp all the way to the edge repeatedly.  Just like on a normal roof you have to tarp all the way to the peak, regardless of the material.

Yeah, In fact extend the tarps a good meter or two past the peak of the roof. Unless you expect a tornado or cyclone it could be good enough to lay down some 2x6 planks to hold the tarp in place.

how do you mean tarp all the way to the edge, of what. the roof? That would not be feasible because there are AC units right uphill from it.

Yes, exactly. You would need to either go over or cut and seal/tape under the units.

The other option is to simply put a bucket or something similar inside, basically flash it to run directly into a containment or catchment basin.
